# Acceder a últimos 12 meses en un objeto con años

Tags: javascript, web

Tengo un objeto que tiene distintos años y cada uno tiene meses con distintos valores.

```
{
    "2020": {
        "1": 69,
        "2": 49,
        "3": 47,
        "4": 6,
        "5": 24,
        "6": 63,
        "7": 46,
        "8": 62,
        "9": 73,
        "10": 56,
        "11": 41,
        "12": 40
    },
    "2021": {
        "1": 76,
        "2": 54,
        "3": 65,
        "4": 82,
        "5": 27,
        "6": 23,
        "7": 49,
        "8": 54,
        "9": 41,
        "10": 58,
        "11": 59,
        "12": 58
    },
    "2022": {
        "1": 67,
        "2": 33
    }
}
```

Editado:

Actualmente lo que hago para acceder a cada año es:

```
Const Ultimos12Meses = Años[2021]

console.log(Ultimos12Meses)

{
        "1": 76,
        "2": 54,
        "3": 65,
        "4": 82,
        "5": 27,
        "6": 23,
        "7": 49,
        "8": 54,
        "9": 41,
        "10": 58,
        "11": 59,
        "12": 58
    },
```

Lo que me devuelve todos los valores de ese año pero yo necesito acceder a los últimos 12 meses desde el año 2022 a el 2021.

Necesito acceder a los últimos 12 meses desde el mes actual del año actual, en ese caso sería desde el 2 del 2022 hasta el 3 del 2021. Pero no se me ocurre una forma de hacerlo con Javascript, ya que necesito que esto se haga de manera automatica a medida que van pasando los meses. Alguna solución?

Gracias!

Comment: Léete [ask] y haz el [tour] para aprender que preguntas son aceptadas en este sitio y el funcionamiento del mismo, y ademas te dan una medalla!! (que veo que no tienes, por eso te lo digo, nunca lo has hecho aun y es importante que aprendas como funciona esta web).   En tu pregunta falta un [example] con el que podamos ayudarte, tan solo dices que no sabes hacerlo, y aqui no hacemos codigo a medida (o no deberiamos). Tampoco se entiende eso de que se "haga de manera automatica". ¿Que quiere decir? ¿Los datos cambian cuando tienes la página cargada? ¿Como?

Comment: Listo edité mi pregunta con un ejemplo. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que quieres algo así:

```js
var Años = {
  "2020": {
    "1": 69,
    "2": 49,
    "3": 47,
    "4": 6,
    "5": 24,
    "6": 63,
    "7": 46,
    "8": 62,
    "9": 73,
    "10": 56,
    "11": 41,
    "12": 40
  },
  "2021": {
    "1": 76,
    "2": 54,
    "3": 65,
    "4": 82,
    "5": 27,
    "6": 23,
    "7": 49,
    "8": 54,
    "9": 41,
    "10": 58,
    "11": 59,
    "12": 58
  },
  "2022": {
    "1": 67,
    "2": 33
  }
}

var fecha = new Date()

function DoceMeses(fecha) {
  anoInicio = fecha.getFullYear() - 1
  switch (fecha.getMonth()) {
    case 11:
      mesInicio = 1
      anoInicio = anoInicio + 1
      break;
    case 12:
      mesInicio = 2
      anoInicio = anoInicio + 1
      break;
    default:
      mesInicio = fecha.getMonth() + 2
      break;
  }
//  mesInicio = fecha.getMonth() + 2
  newarr = []
  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
    newarr.push(Años[anoInicio][mesInicio])
    if (mesInicio == 12) {
      mesInicio = 0
      anoInicio++
    }
    mesInicio++
  }
  return newarr
}
console.log(DoceMeses(fecha))
```

Esto te devuelve un array con los valores que pides, es decir, los últimos 12 meses a partir de la fecha pasada a la función, que en el ejemplo es la actual.

**Explicación detallada**

1. Asignamos a la variable `fecha` un objeto del tipo Date que pasaremos como parámetro a la función. Si no ponemos nada dentro del paréntesis de Date() nos toma la fecha actual, pero podemos poner cualquier fecha en formato **aaaa-mm-dd** y también funcionará (si el objeto **Años** tiene datos que mostrar para esa fecha, claro). Es decir, ponemos esto:

```
var fecha = new Date()
```

2. Creamos una función denominada **DoceMeses()** y en su primera línea vamos a calcular el año donde deben empezar los doce meses, que no puede ser otro que el año anterior a la fecha pasada como parámetro, por lo tanto le restamos 1 y lo hacemos usando el método [getFullYear()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getFullYear):

```
anoInicio = fecha.getFullYear() - 1
```

3. El siguiente paso es calcular el mes, y aquí se complica la cosa, porque tenemos que usar el método [getMonth()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getMonth), el cual devuelve esto:

> El valor devuelto por getMonth() es un entero entre 0 y 11, donde 0
> corresponde a Enero, 1 a Febrero y así sucesivamente.

por lo tanto lo tenemos que tener en cuenta para los cálculos siguientes incrementando en 1 el valor obtenido con ese método para que coincida con los 12 meses "normales".

A esto hay que sumarle una dificultad más, que no podemos usar el mismo mes que hemos obtenido de la variable **fecha** porque nos daria *13* meses en lugar de *12* si contamos desde el año anterior. Es decir, para que sean doce meses no puedo contar desde febrero de un año hasta febrero del otro incluidos ambos, pues nos daria *13* meses en lugar de *12*.  Con lo cual tenemos que sumar de nuevo *1* a los meses obtenidos por el método getMonth(), **y ya van *2* a sumar!!**

Y por si fuera poco, si tenemos que sumar *2* ahora resulta que si el mes pasado es el *11* o el *12* nos vamos a pasar de meses reales y van a ser los meses *13* y *14* respectivamente. Por lo tanto tenemos que contemplar esas excepciones tambien. Así, cuando encontremos un mes *11* y le sumamos dos meses más pasaria a ser el mes *1* y, **atención**, ¡¡del año siguiente!!

Por lo tanto hay que cambiar el valor de la variable `anoInicio` incrementándola en uno en estos dos casos, tanto para el mes *11* y *12*, y dejarla como está para el resto de casos.

Todo esto traducido en código lo interpretamos con una instrucción **switch** del siguiente modo:

```
switch (fecha.getMonth()) {
    case 11:
      mesInicio = 1
      anoInicio = anoInicio + 1
      break;
    case 12:
      mesInicio = 2
      anoInicio = anoInicio + 1
      break;
    default:
      mesInicio = fecha.getMonth() + 2
      break;
  }
```

que dada la explicación anterior no hace falta explicar más.

4. Ahora que ya tenemos lo básico, es decir, el año y el més de inicio de partida, ya podemos contar los *12* meses a partir de ahí con un bucle típico, almacenando su resultado en un *array* que iniciamos antes del bucle, quedando así:

```
newarr = []
  for (i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
```

5. Y dentro del bucle agregamos en este nuevo array los elementos del objeto **Año** mediante *push()* llamándolos por su claves de este modo:

```
newarr.push(Años[anoInicio][mesInicio])
```

He usado esta sintaxis de corchetes porque así me resuelve bien los valores de las variables `anoInicio` y `mesInicio`. Pero a *modo de esquema* seria lo mismo que llamar al valor **Años.anoInicio.mesInicio** (mediante la notación de puntos) del objeto Año.

6. Y para finalizar, de nuevo tenemos un problema con los meses, pues al estar dentro del bucle, es probable que en algun momento se encuentre con el mes *12*, y si lo incrementamos tal cual pasaria a ser el mes *13* en la siguiente iteración/ciclo, y para colmo del mismo año, y no funcionaria bien. Por lo tanto tenemos en cuenta este nuevo caso y hacemos lo siguiente:

```
if (mesInicio == 12) {
      mesInicio = 0
      anoInicio++
    }
mesInicio++
```

Lo cual inicializa de nuevo los meses y pasa de *12* a *1* (fijarse que al salir del condicional incrementamos en *1* el mes para el resto de casos, así que dentro del condicinal lo forzamos en *0* para que al salir coja bien el valor deseado para la siguiente iteración).

Y también dentro del condicional agregamos un año porque al pasar del mes *12* al *1* del año siguiente hay que tenerlo en cuenta y sumárselo.

Al terminar el bucle devolvemos el nuevo *array* con todos los datos recopilados de los *12* meses mediante un:

```
return newarr
```

y salimos de la función.

Nota para el OP: Espero que hayas leído hasta aquí y me lo demuestres en los comentarios, sino te pondré en mi lista negra! :-)

Comment: Gracias! Me sirvió. Me ayudaría mucho que me dieras una pequeña explicación para entender mejor la función.

Comment: Acabo de modificar mi respuesta con nuevo código, porque no tenia en cuenta que pasaba en los meses 11 y 12, que iban a salir mal.  Luego lo explico completo, que ya  lo estaba haciendo cuando me he dado cuenta de eso y cuando estaba terminando se me ha colgado la maquina y he perdido la respuesta completa, que rabia, je

Comment: Vale, ya te acabo de poner la **pequeña** explicación, espero que te sirva. Saludos!